Trying to fix my boot disk on my Ubuntu 22.04 laptop
This morning I could not get into my Ubuntu when starting my laptop, it complained about a missing boot drive (iirc). I used a USB drive with an Ubuntu live session to get access to the system and be able to run Boot-Repair.
Boot Repair info: https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/Q9jcfxcR9G/
============================= Boot Repair Summary ==============================

Default settings: ______________________________________________________________

The default repair of the Boot-Repair utility would not act on the boot.

Confirmation request before suggested repair: __________________________________

You may want to retry after mounting your encrypted partitions so that the tool can verify their contents. (cryptsetup open)
Are you sure you want to continue anyway?

User settings: _________________________________________________________________

You may want to retry after mounting your encrypted partitions so that the tool can verify their contents. (cryptsetup open)
No OS to fix.

=================== /boot detected. Please check the options.
Please backup your data before this operation.
The settings chosen by the user will not act on the boot.

============================ Boot Info After Repair ============================

nvme0n1: _______________________________________________________________________

    File system:       zfs_member
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 

sda: ___________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       iso9660
    Boot sector type:  Unknown
    Boot sector info: 
    Mounting failed:   mount: /mnt/BootInfo/FD/sda: /dev/sda already mounted or mount point busy.


================================ 0 OS detected =================================


================================ Host/Hardware =================================

CPU architecture: 64-bit
Video: GA106M [GeForce RTX 3060 Mobile / Max-Q] Alder Lake-P Integrated Graphics Controller from NVIDIA Corporation Intel Corporation
Live-session OS is Linuxmint 64-bit (Linux Mint 21.2, victoria, x86_64)

===================================== UEFI =====================================

BIOS/UEFI firmware: 1.07.09(7.9) from INSYDE Corp.
The firmware is EFI-compatible, and is set in EFI-mode for this live-session.
SecureBoot disabled (confirmed by mokutil).
BootCurrent: 0000
Timeout: 0 seconds
BootOrder: 2001,2002,2003
Boot0000* EFI USB Device (Intenso Portable SSD) UsbWwid(152d,578,0,DD564198842C)/CDROM(1,0x23c,0x84c0)RC
Boot2001* EFI USB Device    RC
Boot2002* EFI DVD/CDROM RC
Boot2003* EFI Network   RC


============================= Drive/Partition Info =============================

Disks info: ____________________________________________________________________

nvme0n1 : is-GPT,   no-BIOSboot,    has-noESP,  not-usb,    not-mmc, no-os, no-wind,    2048 sectors * 512 bytes

Partitions info (1/3): _________________________________________________________

nvme0n1p1   : no-os,    64, nopakmgr,   no-docgrub, nogrub, nogrubinstall,  no-grubenv, noupdategrub,   not-far
nvme0n1p2   : no-os,    64, nopakmgr,   no-docgrub, nogrub, nogrubinstall,  grubenv-ok, noupdategrub,   not-far

Partitions info (2/3): _________________________________________________________

nvme0n1p1   : isnotESP, part-has-no-fstab,  no-nt,  no-winload, no-recov-nor-hid,   no-bmgr,    notwinboot
nvme0n1p2   : isnotESP, part-has-no-fstab,  no-nt,  no-winload, no-recov-nor-hid,   no-bmgr,    notwinboot

Partitions info (3/3): _________________________________________________________

nvme0n1p1   : maybesepboot, no---boot,  part-has-no-fstab,  not-sep-usr,    no---usr,   part-has-no-fstab,  no--grub.d, nvme0n1
nvme0n1p2   : is---sepboot, no---boot,  part-has-no-fstab,  not-sep-usr,    no---usr,   part-has-no-fstab,  no--grub.d, nvme0n1

fdisk -l (filtered): ___________________________________________________________

Disk nvme0n1: 931.51 GiB, 1000204886016 bytes, 1953525168 sectors
Disk identifier: D546F5D3-47C0-4F24-B598-4562A35D288E
           Start        End    Sectors   Size Type
nvme0n1p1    2048    1050623    1048576   512M Linux filesystem
nvme0n1p2 1050624    4550655    3500032   1.7G Linux filesystem
nvme0n1p3 4550656 1953523711 1948973056 929.3G Linux filesystem
Disk sda: 953.87 GiB, 1024209543168 bytes, 2000409264 sectors
Disk identifier: 0x14eb2669
     Boot   Start        End    Sectors   Size Id Type
sda1  *          0    5138431    5138432   2.5G  0 Empty
sda2           572       9067       8496   4.1M ef EFI (FAT-12/16/32)
sda3       5140480 2000409263 1995268784 951.4G 83 Linux
Disk mapper/myvolume: 929.33 GiB, 997857427456 bytes, 1948940288 sectors
Disk mapper/vgubuntu-root: 927.41 GiB, 995803267072 bytes, 1944928256 sectors
Disk mapper/vgubuntu-swap_1: 1.91 GiB, 2051014656 bytes, 4005888 sectors

parted -lm (filtered): _________________________________________________________

sda:1024GB:scsi:512:4096:msdos:Intenso Portable SSD:;
2:293kB:4643kB:4350kB:::esp;
3:2632MB:1024GB:1022GB:ext4::;
nvme0n1:1000GB:nvme:512:512:gpt:Samsung SSD 980 PRO 1TB:;
1:1049kB:538MB:537MB:ext4:EFI System Partition:;
2:538MB:2330MB:1792MB:ext4::;
3:2330MB:1000GB:998GB:::;

Free space >10MiB: ______________________________________________________________

sda: 4.43MiB:2510MiB:2506MiB

blkid (filtered): ______________________________________________________________

NAME                  FSTYPE      UUID                                   PARTUUID                             LABEL                  PARTLABEL
sda                   iso9660     2023-12-23-05-05-55-00                                                      Boot-Repair-Disk 64bit 
├─sda1                iso9660     2023-12-23-05-05-55-00                 14eb2669-01                          Boot-Repair-Disk 64bit 
├─sda2                vfat        8D6C-A9F8                              14eb2669-02                          ESP                    
└─sda3                ext4        10f7dfc8-090e-4d7a-a3c1-174101478aec   14eb2669-03                          writable               
nvme0n1               zfs_member  16010398127897785890                                                        rpool                  
├─nvme0n1p1           ext4        a1d41f74-6d9f-4434-a197-6fe6e4c9266d   52eb99d3-d854-4dae-b852-151a250097a7 Michel VL Backup       EFI System Partition
├─nvme0n1p2           ext4        e1bce27a-a986-49e3-bb2c-a3e736585fe4   55908fe0-460e-400b-9bf7-e84db83a468e                        
└─nvme0n1p3           crypto_LUKS eb880c35-a1e2-4486-9060-feeae2345586   6aab32e5-ed7b-4bed-bfa3-ff71c297fba9                        
  └─myvolume          LVM2_member fRBSLS-6PXX-2gaS-INh4-gtx9-71RU-p74hlt                                                             
    ├─vgubuntu-root   ext4        41843ba2-6d08-4073-83b8-b250ffd61036                                                               
    └─vgubuntu-swap_1 swap        a7ce9271-3872-4142-b6f1-144ffb191163                                                               

Mount points (filtered): _______________________________________________________

                                                             Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/vgubuntu-root                                     256G  67% /media/mint/41843ba2-6d08-4073-83b8-b250ffd61036
/dev/nvme0n1p1                                              451.3M   0% /mnt/boot-sav/nvme0n1p1
/dev/nvme0n1p2                                              885.1M  40% /mnt/boot-sav/nvme0n1p2
/dev/sda1                                                        0 100% /cdrom

Mount options (filtered): ______________________________________________________

/dev/mapper/vgubuntu-root                                   ext4            rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,errors=remount-ro
/dev/nvme0n1p1                                              ext4            rw,relatime
/dev/nvme0n1p2                                              ext4            rw,relatime
/dev/sda1                                                   iso9660         ro,noatime,nojoliet,check=s,map=n,blocksize=2048,iocharset=utf8

============================== ls -R /dev/mapper/ ==============================

/dev/mapper:
control
myvolume
vgubuntu-root
vgubuntu-swap_1

======================== Unknown MBRs/Boot Sectors/etc =========================

Unknown BootLoader on sda

sprunge.us ko ()

I was able to mount my LUKS volume by running sudo cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/nvme0n1p3 myvolume which mounted it to /media/mint/41843ba2-{long hash here}
I copied out my home folder using rsync to my separate desktop, so that data is backed up for now. If I can't fix the boot disk I can always install Ubuntu 24.04 and go from there, but I'd rather restore my system somehow.
What is my next step to possibly restore my system?
QA while back I switched to Liquorix Kernel (6.8.7-2-liquorix-amd64 I think) to solve some graphics driver issues I had. I have no idea if that plays any role here, though I have no complains about it that so far.

I managed to get to the grub-install step for the empty boot drive and afterwards a successful update-grub
even then did not manage to fix it into a bootable installation.
I'm gonna install 24.04

What I determined happened was that somehow during my workday yesterday I formatted the wrong partition containing my boot drive. Instead one of the external drives I was setting up. And in all the chaos of yesterday I did not notice my boot drive was basically empty for all intents and purposes
Since I managed to backup my data from the LUKS disk by using the Ubuntu live USB the data on the disks was of less importance.
I successfully installed 24.04 over the old partitions by just removing them all and start over.
I gave it a good try to restore the original OS before that, but since this is my work laptop, getting it up and running again was more important then retaining the original installation.
